# Visual studio script not recognizing Cuite_BrowserWindow

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio script is not recognizing **Cuite_BrowserWindow**.
On build I get the following message:

> The name Cuite_browserWindow does not exist in the current context

I have added the following references:
**CodedUIFramework**, **UnitTestFramework**, **UITest.Extension**, **UITesting**

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Was missing a reference to CUITe.Controls.HtmlControls.

Comment: This is such a trivial, specific error, I see no point in keeping it on Stack Overflow. I'd recommend simply deleting the question before it's closed, possibly downvoted, and ultimately deleted.